# When receiving an update for an entity, how to give access to previous values in a class that shouldn't understand incoming DTOs?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

If there are updates for some entity being sent to my backend in the form of a DTO and I have a class that needs access to both the previous values of this entity and the new values, what is a good way to set this up?

The current code looks a bit like this:

```
//temporarily store old values
SomeReferencedEntity previousReferencedEntity = existingObject.getSomeReferencedEntity();
boolean previouslyEnabled = existingObject.isEnabled();
int previousNumber = existingObject.getNumber();

//update entity with new values
existingObject.setSomeReferencedEntity(newSomeReferencedEntity);    //from dto conversion
existingObject.setEnabled(dto.isEnabled());
existingObject.setNumber(dto.getNumber());

//call other class with new and old values
someExternalSystemAdministrator.update(previousReferencedEntity, previouslyEnabled, previousNumber, existingObject);
```

This doesn't seem like a great way to do this though. So what are my options?

- I have thought about instantiating entities from my DTO just so I can
  pass 2 full entities (including references to some other entities I would have to instantiate) to my externalSystemAdministrator class, so we
  can just compare object by object. However that felt like abuse of
  the entity class that I would never actually persist for the new
  values.
- I considered passing the new DTO to the
  externalSystemAdministrator class but there are quite some steps that
  need to be taken before the new values are understandable for that
  class. It also doesn't feel good to let a class like that see any DTO's.
- I could also create some simple value class for the externalSystemAdministrator class to deal with and pass 2 instances of that, instead of passing it my domain entities. This is my favorite option now but it does mean I need to be able to set some values to my actual entities later, based on response of the external system.

Is there a smarter way to set this up? Preferably in a common/standard/accepted way.

Comment: Why don't you use a unique ID to re-query the existing object?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn the entities do have unique ids, that’s not the issue. But I still need access to the old values to determine if I should do (a rather expensive) update call.

Comment: You cannot requery your object in your current service?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn in my code I already have the existing object. It already works as expected. The question is more architectural, meaning I am looking for a way to do this in a neater way than storing the old values in temporary variables 1 by 1 before passing all that to another class (which will do things like updating virtual machines on an external system, not something I want to do unnecessarily)

Answer (score 1):

Create an event that notifies the change. For instance, you will have the event class, represented by a old and new version of your DTO:

```
public class ObjectChangedEvent {
  private MyDto oldValue;
  private MyDto newValue;
  ...
}
```

Then the code you posted above would publish the event after updating the entity:

```
applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(objectChangedEvent);
```

And finally your component that needs to know both versions would be notified of the change:

```
public class MyComponent implements ApplicationListener<ObjectChangedEvent> {

@Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ObjectChangedEvent event) {
        //your logic goes here
    }

}
```

[You can find more details here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-events)

By default Spring make synchronous calls, but I highly recommend you to change to change to asynchronous calls. In this specific case it doesn't seem to change much, but synchronous requests that takes a lot of time to execute might make your application stop answering new requests.

Comment: I totally agree I should move to asynchronous calls, that’s an existing story in my todo. But that doesn’t take away the fact I don’t want the external administrator class to know about the specifics of how to transform my DTO into something readable for that class, which in reality is more complex than getting some primitive values. But your solution most closely matches the third idea in my list, to pass 2 identical objects so that class can just compare those 2. Thanks for the input!